# Can't start elementary OS in UEFI-Mode from USB-Stick

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, uefi, iso, 64-bit

I burned several times the ISO on the USB-Stick. The times I used `dd` I just came to a menu where I can choose the different Versions and after that it stucked in a black-screen.

`sudo dd if=elementaryos-freya-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M;sudo sync;sudo eject /dev/sdb`

The times I used Unetbootin just like mentioned on the elementary website I can install elementary OS but than... in a single boot grub stucked, in a dual boot the other distro just starts.

With the Ubuntu ISO the dd-buring and folowing UEFI installation works without any problem. (I choosed a gpt-partition table for the harddrive)

My System is a TP-X250, i3-5010U, HD5500, SSD

In UEFI I have the setup: UEFI only, CSM off, fasboot

Greetings